# Use cache from other query in transformResponse

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I've been searching around for an answer to this, but I've not had any luck.
I'm new to RTK Query, but so far so good.

I have two queries where I want to transform the response of the second query, based on the cached response of the first.

Currently the both queries run at the same time as they have been independent of each other until now, but I would need to change it so that I wait on the first query before running the second. In this application, it is not a problem since the two queries a part of the initialisation of the app. The data is not mutated during the session.

The first query fetches a really large JSON object from the database which is basically just an array of objects. The second query fetches some configuration from the database, but needs to read the data from the first query to transform and enhance some of the configuration data. I do not have access to the backend so I cannot do the work on the server before fetching.

Here is an idea what I want to be able to do:

```js
const myApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'myApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getFirst: builder.query({
      query: () => '/getFirst',
    }),
    getSecond: builder.query({
      query: () => '/getSecond',
      transformResponse: (response) => {
        ...
        // Transform data using cached data from 'getFirst' query
        ...
        return { ... };
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

Is this possible or am I approaching it the wrong way? Feel free to request any extra information which may be useful.

Comment: Is "getSecond" ***always*** called when "getFirst" is called? What is the relationship between these two endpoints? Can you [edit] to clarify the use case?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DrewReese. I've added some clarifications. You can assume that getSecond will always get called when getFirst gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both APIs are always called together, the first and the second, then why not combine them into a single endpoint, e.g. `getFirstAndSecond`?

See [Performing Multiple Requests with a Single Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#performing-multiple-requests-with-a-single-query) for details.

Basic gist is to use a custom query function to call one API, await it, then call the other, await it, and merge the results.

Example:

```js
const myApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'myApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getFirstAndSecond: builder.query({
      queryFn: async (arg, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        const [results1, results2] = await Promise.all([
          baseQuery('/getFirst'),
          baseQuery('/getSecond'),
        ]);

        // logic to use both results and compute query value to cache/return
        return {
          data: .... the computed value ....
        };
      }
    }),
  }),
});
```